# C function to a macro

Tags: c, function, macros

I need to write a macro instead of a function in C

The function is as follows :

```
void FSTATUS(int stat,char msg[])
{
    if(stat != 0)
    {
        EMH_ask_error_text(stat, &msg);
        printf("Error : \"%d\",\"%s\"\n",stat,msg);
    }
    else 
        printf("\n -------- %s -------- \n",msg);
}
```

as there are very less examples available how to use if statement in macros , I am stuck with this part where I am not able to figure out how to convert this into a macro. Can anyone please help me out with the above code.

Solution :

I used an inline function instead of a macro

Comment: What makes you think this needs to be a macro ???

Comment: I need to call this as a macro to decrease the compilation time

Comment: Oh, you will not decrease the compilation time, you can just increase it if you are using macros. Remember that macros are expanding into your source code before compilation.

Comment: Why not simply use an `inline` ?

Comment: Hey inline is also a good alternative ! thanks @perror!

Answer (score 6):

```
#define FSTATUS(stat, msg) do \
{ \
    if((stat) != 0) \
    { \
        EMH_ask_error_text(stat, &(msg)); \
        printf("Error : \"%d\",\"%s\"\n",stat,msg); \
    } \
    else  \
        printf("\n -------- %s -------- \n",msg); \
} while (0)
```

Note the use of `do { ... } while (0)` to ensure that this works correctly between `if`/`else`.

Note also the use of additional parentheses in some places to avoid problems when `stat` or `msg` is an expression.

And of course be very aware of all the pitfalls of macros - you really should not use this type of function macro unless you have a very good reason to. Ideally you should use an inline function if performance really is critical, otherwise just stick with a normal function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. the arguments I am passing are int stat and char msg[] i.e. an array.. So how do I pass an array??

Comment: I tried #define FSTATUS(int stat,char[] msg) but its showing a syntaxerror

Comment: @Neal: for a macro you don't specify the argument types - so you obviously lose the type checking that you get with a function. It's up to you to provide the correct arguments. In general this type of macro is a bad idea (for this and a number of other reasons) but hopefully you know what you're doing...

Comment: I wonder why is the do-while loop necessary. Can you explain?

Comment: @lulyon The do while loop lets you do two things: 1. write the call to the macro as a regular function call with a ; at the end, and no warnings about empty statements; 2. (doesn't apply in this case) if you have any local variables which are only needed within the body of the macro it gives you a block scope within which to define them.

Answer (score 4):

Proper formatting makes a huge difference, I believe.  That's why I always align `\`'s.

```
#define FSTATUS(stat, msg)                                \
do                                                        \
{                                                         \
    if ((stat) != 0)                                      \
    {                                                     \
        EMH_ask_error_text((stat), &(msg));               \
        printf("Error : \"%d\",\"%s\"\n", (stat), (msg)); \
    }                                                     \
    else                                                  \ 
    {                                                     \
        printf("\n -------- %s -------- \n", (msg));      \
    }                                                     \
}                                                         \
while (0)
```

Important: Make sure there's no white space behind the `\` at the end of the lines.  White space 'breaks' the line-break.

Of course you could also do:

```
#define FSTATUS(s, m) ((s) ? (EMH_ask_error_text((s), &(m)), printf("Error : \"%d\",\"%s\"\n", (s), (m))) : printf("\n -------- %s -------- \n", (m)))
```

Here the comma operator is used as separator between the two statements in the `if`-block.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define FSTATUS(stat,msg) \
do {                       \
    if(stat != 0)           \
    {                        \
        EMH_ask_error_text(stat, &msg);  \
        printf("Error : \"%d\",\"%s\"\n",stat,msg); \
    }  \                     \
    else \
        printf("\n -------- %s -------- \n",msg);\
}while(0)
```

Only need to do is changing the function type to macro. If you wonder why need to add do {.. } while(0) ,you can reference this :http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Swallowing-the-Semicolon.html#Swallowing-the-Semicolon

Comment: You're missing a few \ s